# Обозначение границ слова с помощью регулярных выражений в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Так, есть, условно, задача:
дана строка '**X**ABAD**X**JSAD**Z**FNEFE**X**NN**Z**FWUFNWFN**X**UNNINNU**Z**AFE' (для примера, только заглавные латинские буквы).
Необходимо вывести все подпоследовательности, начинающиеся на X и заканчивающиеся Z:
**X**JSAD**Z**,
**X**NN**Z**,
**X**UNNINNU**Z**,
При этом между X и Z не может быть X, т.е. строка **X**ABAD**X**JSAD**Z** не должна попасть в вывод
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В условии регулярки указываем, что ожидаем `X<любые символы кроме X>Z`

```
import re

text = 'XABADXJSADZFNEFEXNNZFWUFNWFNXUNNINNUZAFE'

print(re.findall('X[^X]+Z', text))
# ['XJSADZ', 'XNNZ', 'XUNNINNUZ']
```

Comment: Я вот думаю `+` или `*`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, кст, да... Но раз автор принял ответ, то похоже наличие элементов между `X` и `Z` является нормой :)